# How do I disable the line count warning on the Lint tool?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2015, lint

The Lint tool for F# interprets comments and white space as lines of code. Thus, a warning is generated.

I think this is a bug.

Is there a way for me to disable the analyzer for counting lines on the Lint tool?

[image]

Comment: you can open an issue on github

Comment: @yuyoyuppe It is not a bug, it is a feature that can be enabled or disabled.

Comment: @GuyCoder `interprets comments and white space as lines of code` can this be disabled?

Comment: @yuyoyuppe Thanks for clarifying, I now agree with your comment.

Comment: As noted by yuyoyuppe the answer I gave is not a complete answer to your question. Since F# Lint is a [GitHub project](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpLint) you could update it and submit a pull request. I am sure it will take you time to do, but would be a great way to learn more about F# and give back to the community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are configuration options for Lint.

Visual Studio must be exited and restarted for the change to take effect.

[image]

### Details for manually changing configuration

F# Lint uses an XML for [configuration](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpLint/blob/master/src/FSharpLint.Framework/DefaultConfiguration.FSharpLint)

which for my system is located in the `src\FSharpLint.Framework` directory.

For [Lambda Functions maximum lines](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpLint/blob/master/src/FSharpLint.Framework/DefaultConfiguration.FSharpLint#L188) there is:

```
 <MaxLinesInLambdaFunction> 
     <Enabled>true</Enabled> 
     <Lines>7</Lines> 
 </MaxLinesInLambdaFunction>
```

which also allows for the changing of the number of lines.

### Details for Visual Studio

For Visual Studio from the menu

Tools -> Option

[image]

In the left panel select: F# Power Tools
Click on: Lint

[image]

In right panel
Select tab: Rules
Click Source Length

[image]

The message about lines in a lambda function is controlled by the option:

> MaxLinesInLambdaFunction

[image]

If enabled the warning message is displayed.

[image]

If disabled the warning message is NOT displayed.

[image]